# Load the page content using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Using jQuery load html forms dynamically using append function. Here the following code load the page content dynamically based on number times of values on while loop.

Here I have a struggle on load the content with different values.its working with single value of 0 or 1 on var load_with_value=0; but not on both simultaneously i.e. increment the load_with_value++ for again load the page content of HTML forms.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("<DIV>").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", function() //url for loading page
    {
        var n = $('.item').length + 1;           //load the html page content 
        var i = 1;                              //iteration for number of times load the content
        var count = 2;                         //check the condition
        var load_with_value = 0;              //load the page content with different values for display different values on html form  

        while(i<count) {                      //loop starts
            $("#product").append($(this).html());
            i++;
            load_with_value++;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @john.please help me do this..

Comment: @john ? Jon Skeet ? Yeah he will definately get in touch with you shortly.

Comment: The code comments make no sense..

Comment: @Dropout I need of first its load with 0 on var=load_with_values and load with 1 for append html.

Comment: @navaskhan it's hard to understand what you want to achieve from the question.. I did my best down in the answer section. Hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all let's do some proper code formatting and get rid of the incorrect comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("<DIV>").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", function() {
        var n = $('.item').length + 1;           
        var i = 1;                              
        var count = 2; 
        var load_with_value = 0;           
        while(i<count) {
            $("#product").append($(this).html());
            i++;
            load_with_value++;
        }
    });
});
```

Now let's take it apart:

If you want to use a *temporary element* to store the loaded data you need to assign it to a variable, so instead of

```
$("<DIV>").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", function() {
```

do

```
var tempObject = $("<div/>").load("<?php echo $url; ?>", function() {
```

Afterwards you can append the temporary element to an existing one with `$('#someExistingElement').append(tempObject)`.

If you want to load the content into an existing element you should use it's ID, class or other selector to do this - not `$("<div>")`.. If you want to load it to all div elements (please don't) then it should be `$("div")`.

Next `var n = $('.item').length + 1;` makes no sense. It is never used in the code.

While cycle in this case is unnecessary. Don't use while cycles if you don't have to. You can use:

```
for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
    //code
}
```

What is `var load_with_value = 0;` used for? I can only see you incrementing it with `load_with_value++;` but you don't use it anywhere..

Finally if you want to load different content based on the incremented variable it should be done outside of the `.load` function.. For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i=0; i<5; i++){
        $('#container-' + i).load('/somecontent-' + i + '.html');
    }
});
```

This loads the content `/somecontent-0.html` to `/somecontent-4.html` into container elements with IDs `container-0` to `container-4` respectively.

Comment: thanks man its really help for me.but load function with in for loop is not working

Comment: @navaskhan in what way is it not working? does it send the load requests? do you get any errors in the console? check the developer console.. (F12)

Comment: In url field for it have the php file to load with html content. $(document).ready(function(e) {
    for(var i=1;i<2;i++)
 {
    $('#product-' + i).load('<?php echo $url;?>' + i + '.html');
 }
});    <DIV id="product">
       <?php include("buyinput.php");  ?>
        </DIV> this is what i did.

Comment: @Dropout.I am more struggle on this.help me please

Comment: @navaskhan in what way is it not working? do you get any errors?

Comment: @navaskhan do you have any errors in the console? are the load requests being sent (see networking tab in console)?

Comment: no i am not get a error. simple append also not working.function appendSomeItems() {
  for (var i=1; i<2; i++) {
    $('#product').append($('#product').html());
  }
  
}

appendSomeItems();

Comment: @navaskhan hold on. Your for cycle goes from 1 to 2. That means it only loads the `-1.html` content. You should have used `for(var i=0; i<2; i++){` as I wrote in the answer..

Comment: @navaskhan if you want to load contents 0 and 1, then it's `i=0; i<2` if you want to load 1 and 2 then it's `i=1; i<=2` or `i=1; i<3`..

Comment: @Dropout.yes..exactly what i need is load the page with dynamic created textbox with fetching multiple record from db and store into the text box as increment 1,2,3 so on.

Comment: @navaskhan as I said in the last comment, fix your cycle so it goes over the numbers you need.. for example if you need to load contents from 1 to  300 then the cycle should look like this: `for(var i=1; i<=300; i++){`